# JoJo timeline problems

Tags: jojos-bizarre-adventure

So recently, I found an article about how the author got rid of hamon in JoJo. It said that he replaced hamon with stands since it was outdated or something. Now, this is after two parts of JoJo. So I was wondering about the JoJo series 2000 and the one before that. They had the same storyline as Stardust Crusaders, meaning that it had stands. So since these two series came way before 2012 series which had hamon, why did the author had to 'get rid' or hamon when stands were already present and they were to be used in Stardust Crusaders?

Comment: You're aware that the author began writing the manga in 1987, right?

Comment: F1Krazy no I wasn't aware of that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The chronology of *JoJo* adaptations goes like this:

- **1987-1989:** Hirohiko Araki publishes the first two parts of *JoJo's Bizarre Adventure*, *Phantom Blood* and *Battle Tendency*. These parts both focus on the power of Hamon.
- **1989-1992:** Araki publishes Part 3, *Stardust Crusaders*. While writing this part, Araki introduces the concept of Stands, and these go on to replace Hamon as the series' main supernatural force.
- **1993-1994:** A six-part OVA is released that adapts the second half of *Stardust Crusaders*, skipping over the first two parts entirely.
- **2000-2002:** A seven-part OVA is released that adapts the first half of *Stardust Crusaders*, thus acting as a prequel to the earlier OVA series.
- **2012 onwards:** A TV anime begins that adapts the entire manga from the beginning. To stay true to the manga, the adaptations of *Phantom Blood* and *Battle Tendency* retain the concept of Hamon.

(For simplicity's sake, I've omitted the publication dates for Parts 4 through 8 of the manga. Only the first three parts are relevant to your question.)